# React Native: WebView load static local file

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently using WebView to load a static page using `require`. But that html file includes some images, css, js files in it. It still works on Android, ios debugger, but doesn't work on real device.

How can I bundle all resource files for released app and what path will they be located? I want a path like `{uri: 'file://.../index.html'}`

I don't want to upload file to online server, it just a static page, I want my app can run without connecting to internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... I end up with ios finally, it's so hard to get URI path of file `index.html`. But I found out alternative solution.

For Android, just copy file to `android/app/src/main/assets`. Example:

> File `android/app/src/main/assets/web/index.html` will have
>   URI path is `file:///android_asset/web/index.html`.

For ios, it's not easy like Android. I have used third-party library named [react-native-fs](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs).

1. We need to copy static file/folder to ios project using Xcode.
2. Use react-native-fs to list all files/folders in main bundle and filter them: [Example Code](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs#basic)

This is my code for ios to get URI path of `web/index.html`:

```
if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        const results = await RNFS.readDir(RNFS.MainBundlePath);
        const webFolder = results.filter(f => f.name == 'web');
        this.setState({fireworkURI: 'file://' + webFolder[0].path + '/index.html'})
    }
```

Another approach is serving static folder as http server, this approach will be easier for programming, but I don't like it because of low performance. For anyone interested in this approach, have a look at [react-native-httpserver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-httpserver)

Comment: This solution is not working on React Native 0.44 on Android.

Comment: @Rai you can try react-native-fs for alternate

Answer (score 0):

WebView `react-native-webview` corrently does not support loading local files according to the [documentation](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/0817524326a882107ed1994d3861212b382f054d/docs/Guide.md#loading-local-html-files).

A recommended solution is to host the local files using a local web server such as `react-native-static-server`, a lightweight web server that runs on the target device.

I personally tried to implement this solution. The web server runs on the Android phone but I don't know how to ship the static pages with the app.

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
import StaticServer from 'react-native-static-server';

const ws_path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/'; 
const server = new StaticServer(8080, ws_path, { localOnly: true });

export default class mayApp extends Component {
 ...
 componentDidMount() {
  // start the web server
  server.start().then((url) => {
   this.ws_url = url;      // I tried this too: url + '/index.html';
   console.log("Serving at URL", this.ws_url);
   console.log("path", ws_path);
  });
 }
 ...
 <WebView source={{ uri: this.ws_url}} />
}
```

The result is:

```
 LOG  Serving at URL http://localhost:8080
 LOG  path /data/user/0/com.vote/files/
```

This path does not exist on my device `/data/user/0/com.vote/files/`. The most similar place I can find is `This PC/MY PHONE NAME/Internal shared storage/Android/data/com.myApp/files/index.html`

Can anybody help with this?

How to ship/bundle the static files into a given path on the device?

**UPDATE:**

The solution provided by @Viet Phan sometimes work but the behavior is not predictable.

```
<WebView source={{ uri: "file:///android_asset/index.html" }} />
```